# dcpromo /forceremoval as a file server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, file-permissions, controller

I'm working on a customers infrastructure where most of the DCs were not replicating with each other. I managed to bring up another two DC's, bring them to the domain and switch over the FSMO roles.

There's one 2008R2 DC left which I can't gracefully remove and I will need to force remove it, however this one server also turns out to be the only file server for the business. If I perform a dcpromo /forceremoval on this DC, which automatically removes the server from the domain, will it lose the folder permissions? I'm planning on making this a member server again after the removal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The SID's and GUID attributes will be retained**

You will see question marks regarding the NTFS permissions within the directory structure after you force remove the host from the domain.

After you rejoin the system it will remap all of the SID's and GUID's and you will see the username associated to the GUID's and SID's again.

Comment: I thought this may be the case but just needed to double check, so I didn't have to setup all the permissions again. It worked, thanks!

Comment: All good.  Welcome to the site.  Cheers!